# asp:panel not going invisble from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the deal. I have several elements that I may or may not want to have displayed on a user interface that are controlled by table in a database. So based on a value I have stored I want to either display the control to the user or not.  In order to deal with this I placed all the controls I am using on the page and put them inside of panels each with a unique ID so that they can be addressed by panelname.visible=true/false in code behind.

Before building the code behind structure for this I tested the effect by adding the attribute to the panel on the asp.net page and I was pleased with the results.

I tested one with code behind and it worked great! so I built the rest and tried it and suddenly it didn't work!

Here is what I'm doing tell me if you see something wrong here! I'm baffled the panel should be hiding but it isn't the reference bool is False from the DB.

The ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Sys1pnl" >
   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="SysChkBX1" Value="AIX 6.1" Text="&nbsp;AIX 6.1" BackColor="DeepSkyBlue" Font-Size="X-Small"  />
   <br />
</asp:Panel>
```

The Code Behind Code:

```
if (ElementsVal.AIX_6_1 == true)
  Sys1pnl.Visible = true;
   else
  Sys1pnl.Visible = false;
```

In all cases the panels and content remain visible, even though they should be hidden (invisible).

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.
Ken...

Comment: What is `ElementsVal.AIX_6_1` supposed to represent in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend to actually check the value that is stored within your `CheckBox` itself?

If that is the case, then you could just use the `Value` property and see if it meets your condition and then hide accordingly :

```
// This will show / hide your panel based on if the value of your Checkbox is "AIX 6.1"
Sys1pnl.Visible = (SysChkBX1.Value == "AIX 6.1");
```

Comment: No this check box doesn't control if the checkbox itself is visible the matrix that controls that is administered on a different panel from a different page.   And after posting this I went back and realized that I have one section work and 3 others not so I just have to figure out what I messed up on the three others.  The two tables (the one holding the values check and not check and the one that indicates which panels are displayed) got confused in my mind here as I was writing this up.

Answer (score 0):

Well since it was working before adding your other logic, it means nothing wrong with the code you shared. 
I advise you to revert your latest changes and add your features one by one to see which one is causing the problem.

Another idea is to check the Javascript debugger of the page from inspecting your page from your browser. If there is an error with html, an error will be shown there.